# Angular SharedModule causing 'is not know error'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have navbar component and I created a module for that component named 'NavbarModule' because I want to share it. I want to use this component in 'ProductsListComponent'. Even if  I imported and exported NavbarComponent in NavbarModule and  imported NavbarModule in ProductsListComponent it gives  'app-navbar' is not a known element' error.

**navbar.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
declarations: [NavbarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports:[
    NavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class NavbarModule { }
```

**product-list.module.ts**

```
import { NavbarComponent } from 'src/app/components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { NavbarModule } from 'src/app/components/navbar/navbar.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProductsListRoutingModule } from './products-list-routing.module';
import { ProductsListComponent } from './products-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductsListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsListRoutingModule,
    NavbarModule,
  ]
  ,exports:[ProductsListComponent]
})
export class ProductsListModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure you are already correct in the import and export part. Maybe just restart the cli? close and ng build/ng serve again.